# Positron - Photon feynman diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, feynman, tikz-feynman

I made a simple Feynman diagram of the channel S=(k1 + k2)^2 in the Positron - Photon scattering as follows

```
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b]{
    i1 [particle=\(\gamma\)] 
        -- [photon, momentum=\(\vec{k}_1\)] a -- [fermion, momentum'=\(\vec{k}_2\)] i2 [particle=\(e^{+}\)],
    a -- [anti fermion, edge label'=\((\vec{k}_1+\vec{k}_2)\)] b,
    f1 [particle=\(\gamma\)] 
        -- [photon, momentum'=\(\vec{k}_3\)] b -- [anti fermion, momentum=\(\vec{k}_4\)] f2 [particle=\(e^{+}\)],
};
```

The problem is that the k2 and k3 arrows are not in the correct direction. How may I do it to get the correct one? I do not get how to build this S channel properly.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Use `reversed momentum` (or `rmomentum`) as described in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-feynman/tikz-feynman.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b]{
    i1 [particle=\(\gamma\)] 
        -- [photon, momentum=\(\vec{k}_1\)] a -- [fermion, reversed momentum'=\(\vec{k}_2\)] i2 [particle=\(e^{+}\)],
    a -- [anti fermion, edge label'=\((\vec{k}_1+\vec{k}_2)\)] b,
    f1 [particle=\(\gamma\)] 
        -- [photon, reversed momentum'=\(\vec{k}_3\)] b -- [anti fermion, momentum=\(\vec{k}_4\)] f2 [particle=\(e^{+}\)],
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to Henri Menke's nice answer: follow the particle lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b]{
    i1 [particle=\(\gamma\)] 
        -- [photon, momentum=\(\vec{k}_1\)] a,
    i2 [particle=\(e^{+}\)]  -- [anti fermion, momentum=\(\vec{k}_2\)] a,
    a -- [anti fermion, momentum'=\((\vec{k}_1+\vec{k}_2)\)] b,
    b -- [anti fermion, momentum=\(\vec{k}_4\)] f2 [particle=\(e^{+}\)],
    b -- [photon, momentum=\(\vec{k}_3\)]   f1 [particle=\(\gamma\)]
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]